# Change vue's expansion panel expanded text

Tags: vuetify.js

How can i toggle the text displayed when a user toggles the expanded state of an expansion panel? I thought this would work but the 'open' value doesn't appear to trigger correctly.

```
<!-- Details -->
    <v-expansion-panels flat hover>
      <v-expansion-panel>
        <v-expansion-panel-header disable-icon-rotate>
          {{ title }}
          <template v-slot:actions>
            <span v-if="open" class="overline text--disabled">Show Details</span>
            <span v-else class="overline text--disabled">Hide Details</span>
          </template>
        </v-expansion-panel-header>
        <v-expansion-panel-content>
          <v-row>
            <v-col cols="4">somos</v-col>
            <v-col cols="4">somos</v-col>
            <v-col cols="4">somos</v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-expansion-panel-content>
      </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-expansion-panels>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are using vuetify v2, but I guess it.

So to get the "open" value, you must to use the `default` slot:

```
<v-expansion-panel>
  <!-- add expand-icon="" to remove the arrow icon -->
  <v-expansion-panel-header disable-icon-rotate expand-icon="">
    <template v-slot:default="{ open }">
        <v-row no-gutters>
          <v-col cols="4">{{ title }}</v-col>
          <v-col cols="4"></v-col>
          <v-col cols="4">
            <span v-if="!open" key="0" class="overline text--disabled">Show Details</span>
            <span v-else key="1" class="overline text--disabled">Hide Details</span>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </template>
  </v-expansion-panel-header>
  <v-expansion-panel-content>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="4">somos</v-col>
      <v-col cols="4">somos</v-col>
      <v-col cols="4">somos</v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-expansion-panel-content>
</v-expansion-panel>
```

You can use the header as you consider, I mean, without v-row or v-col:

```
<v-expansion-panel-header disable-icon-rotate v-slot="{ open }" expand-icon="">
  <v-layout align-center justify-space-between/>
    title
    <span v-if="open" key="0" class="overline text--disabled">Show Details</span>
    <span v-else key="1" class="overline text--disabled">Hide Details</span>
  </v-layout>
</v-expansion-panel-header>
```